# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Tags: laravel-6

Tengo un problema para que en vez de mostrar el `status_id`, me lo convierta en el nombre. He revisado el código varias veces y comparado con otra app donde hago lo mismo y aquí si me funciona. Espero que me podáis echar un cable.

En la base de datos tengo dos tablas. La de `users` donde se almacenan varios campos y uno de ellos es un `id` de otra tabla, `status_id` con su clave foránea.

En la otra tabla `status_users`, solo hay dos campos -> `id` y `name`.

```
Modelo para la base de datos
----------------------------

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class StaUser extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'status_user';

    // Relación Many to One con los usuarios
    public function status_user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'status_id');
    }

}
```

'''

```
Controlador
-----------

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class UsuariosController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
      $usuarios = User::orderBy('nick')->get();

        return view('usuarios.usuarios', [
          'usuarios' => $usuarios,
        ]);
    }
}
```

'''

```
Vista
-----

   @foreach ($usuarios as $usuario)
   <tr class="text-center">
      <td class="align-middle">{{ $usuario->status_user->name }}</td> <-- Aquí me arroja el error !!
      <td class="align-middle">Imagen - {{ $usuario->nick }}</td>
      <td class="align-middle">Rol</td>
      <td class="align-middle">{{ $usuario->name }}</td>
      <td class="align-middle">{{ $usuario->surname }}</td>
      <td class="align-middle">{{ $usuario->email }}</td>
      <td class="align-middle">{{ $usuario->created_at }}</td>
```

Comment: podrías publicar tu modelo de usuario para ayudarte mejor

Comment: Hola, gracias por vuestro interés. Os pongo la solución para que les valga a los demás. Resulta que mi 'many to one' lo ponía en el modelo de 'StaUser', y debe estar en el modelo 'User' ya que es un método de éste.  Por eso al intentar acceder del modo -> 'user->status_user->name' me decía que el objeto no existía.  Gracias !!